# Is there any case in which I should use unicode as a type in Python 3 docstrings?

Tags: python, docstring

I'm porting a library from Python 2 to Python 3 and now I'm working on the docstrings. I wonder if I could safely replace all occurrences of unicode type with str in docstrings, since all strings in Python 3 are stored as unicode, or if on the other hand is there any potential case in Python 3 where a type should be specified as unicode.

Comment: Generally speaking, that should be the right thing to do. The tricky part is deciding whether a Python 2 `str` should be a Python 3 `str` or `bytes`.

Comment: @chepner why tricky? In your case shouldn't it be as simple as replacing `str` with `bytes` and `unicode` with `str`?

Comment: "Tricky" is proably the wrong word. Without worrying about whether I'm being 100% accurate, I would say that `unicode` is *always* replaced with `str`, and Python-2 `str` is sometimes replaced with Python 3 `str` and sometimes Python-3 `bytes`, depending on how the Python-2 `str`'s value is being interpreted. (Was it representing encoded, usually ASCII, text, or was it representing arbitrary binary data?) In Python 3, all encoded text (ASCII, UTF-8, whatever) is treated as arbitrary binary data in a `bytes` value until explicitly decoded into a Unicode `str` value.

Comment: In short, you should be able to replace everything expect [literal declarations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)

Comment: @chepner in the library I'm porting there's some docstrings containing descriptions like `unicode or str`, so I assume it always refers to `str` to imply `bytes` and not `unicode`. Is it a correct assumption?

Comment: @xilopaint Probably not. Sounds more like an acknowledgment that either `unicode` or `str` might be used to represent text. (Typically, people used `str` as long as the text was restricted to ASCII or whatever encoding the Python source code itself used, e.g. `'föö'`. `unicode` was mostly reserved for characters not typically found in an 8-bit character set, or for handling text without worrying out encodings.)